# Shopify - Facing issue when creating customer using shopify api

Tags: javascript, react-native, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

im working on shopify project to develop the android app. Currently im facing issue when creating customer. im tried to solve it if someone know about this please help me out!

**Create customer mutation query**

```
const query= `mutation customerCreate($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
      customerCreate(input: $input) {
        customer {
          acceptsMarketing
          email
          firstName
          lastName
          password
          phone
        }
        customerUserErrors {
          field
          message
          code
        }
        variables: {
          "input": {
            "acceptsMarketing": true,
            "email": "johnsmith@shopify.com",
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "password": "5hopify",
            "phone": "111111111111"
          }
        },
      }
    }`;

async function apiCall(query) {
return fetch('https://storename.myshopify.com/api/graphql.json', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
    'Access-Control-Origin': '*',
    'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': token,
  },
  body: query,
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log('response: ', response))
  .catch(error => console.log('error: ', error.message));
```

}

**facing the below error**

```
{"errors": [{"locations": [Array], "message": "Parse error on \"{\" (LCURLY) at [16, 20]"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following query. its worked for me

```
mutation  {
  customerCreate(
    input: {
      firstName: "dave",
      lastName: "smith",
      email: "someone@gmail.com",
      password: "12345"
      acceptsMarketing: true,
      
        }
  ) {
    customer {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
      email
    }
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
    customer {
      id
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you there's a parse* error on line 16 column 20. Parse errors usually point to typos, and my best guess is the `:` you have after `variables` on line 16 - is that symbol supposed to be there?

Comment: ok sir let me check

Comment: @ijazbacha Use a tool like https://jsonformatter.org/graphql-formatter/ to correctly format your GraphQL and to find errors. It seems like the error you're seeing right now is only one of many.

Comment: now the query is valid but still im facing the following error
**Field 'email' doesn't exist on type 'CustomerCreatePayload'"**
`mutation {
      customerCreate(
        input: {
          email: "abc@gmail.com"
          firstName: "test"
          lastName: "test"
          password: "12345678"
          phone: "+12121212121"
        }
      ) 
       {
        email
        firstName
        lastName
        password
        phone
      }
      customerUserErrors {
        field
        message
        code
      }
    }`